# Is there a web client SDK for microsofts BotFramework

Tags: javascript, botframework

I want to create my own chat using bot framework.

I managed to set up whole backend and now I'm stuck with frontend. I see that Microsoft has this :

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/

But documentation is poor + I'm using Angular and I want to create my own chat control. So I'm looking a library that simply allows to send and receive messages over webchat channel.

Is there something like this already?

Answer (score 0):

Webchat is what you want. Webchat is very robust, very customizable and has many options. I don't know if you've looked at more than just the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/docs) folder, but the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples) has many examples on how to do many things. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.getting-started) would be a good place to get started.

You could of course build your own as a [Direct Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) client, but with all that webchat already does, I'm not sure why you would want to start from scratch.